# Replace original srids with new ones

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, insert

[image: Demo Tables]

As you can see, I have got 2 tables here, table 1 and table 2. The column **srid** in Table 1 is an identity column.

Table 2 is like a child table of table 1, where we can link table 2 with table 1 by using **srid** column.

Now what I would like to achieve is to sort of replace the original **srid**, i.e. 1,2,3 with the new ones, i.e. 4,5,6, while in the mean time we keep its original **crvalue** unchanged. And then we will insert it back into table 2.

I find replacing new srids is a bit challenging and get stuck. So what query/script should I write to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY srid)
  FROM Table1
)
UPDATE t2
SET srid = new.srid
FROM Table2 t2
  INNER JOIN ranked old ON old.uid = 1 AND old.srid = t2.srid
  INNER JOIN ranked new ON new.uid = 2 AND new.rank = old.rank
```

Basically, you are ranking `srid` values within each `uid` group and then joining the two subsets by the ranks to associate every old `srid` with a new one. Naturally, you are joining `Table2` with the old `srid` subset too, of course.

Answer (score 0):

based on this simple example i think you could inner join the tables like this

...FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.srid = Table2.srid + 3...

you will then insert Table1.srid and Table2.crvalue into the new table.  These results should return your last table. I hope this helps.

Comment: Join table 1 and table 2 is not hard at all but the problem I really got here was I need to join table 2 itself, which is kinda impossible. Note that I only care about the Table 2 where I need to get my srid updated with the new ones while the crvalue needs to stay the same.

Comment: @woodykiddy It'd be easy if it was just an int field, you could use the simple update query below, but since it is an Id field it's not going to allow you to update the value...
UPDATE Table2
SET srid = srid + 3

However, i don't know your access constraints, nor do i recommend this as a normal practice...that being said, you could go into design change that field to no longer be an ID field, update the values using the update query above and then go back into design and change it back to and ID field.  As i said certainly not a best practice, but i think it should work. Thoughts?